# Eclipse Juno replicates all interface annotations in the implementing class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I'm using Jersey in a SmartGwt project and recently imported it to Eclipse Juno 4.2.
In Indigo, I could declare the annotations in the resource interface and the implementing class would just contain an @Override annotation.
When I created the implementing class in Juno, **all** the annotations were included.
(i.e. the @GET, @Path, @Produces etc.)
I'm by no means an Eclipse pro and was wondering if there's a Windows->preferences setting I missed?
Is this a bug? Or is this the "new normal"?

Comment: Noticed the same thing, also because I'm using Jersey.  This is a bit of a pain because the the Jersey annotations need to be on one or the other... If any exist on the class at all, then it doesn't look at the interface at all anymore for annotations.  
  
I haven't found the setting yet anywhere either

Comment: Same thing for JAX-WS WebService annotations